# How can I precisely measure the intensity of the Hydrogen Alpha (Balmer) line at low intensities?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics

I assume that I will need some kind of very precise filtering, but how is that accomplished? After that, photon counting at worst, but I am expecting millions of photons per second.
The background is ionized Oxygen and Nitrogen with a bit of CO2 and Argon (air)

Comment: Do you have a spectrometer? How good of one? How much post-processing are you interested in doing? If straight measurement isn't good enough, how about correlation spectroscopy? How small does it have to be?  Lots of questions...

Comment: None of the above. I am sketching out requirements - simplest and cheapest first! Ideally I want the system weighing under 5kg. I need to know whether it is possible.

Comment: There is a wide range of work on portable stand-off detection of gases in air. Sadly, I can't point you to specific articles, but would suggest SPIE proceedings. You might also look at polychromator spectrometers (perhaps polytec.com, others may exist).

Comment: Assuming that there are no other spectral lines close to the line a simple $H_\alpha$ filter should to the trick.   Millions of photons a second are easily detected with a photodiode. If the signal to noise due to the background is not good enough, you need to find a way to modulate the signal (e.g. by varying the ratio between the gases or the excitation). As for "precisely", that's always a relative term in photometric measurements. It's usually very hard to get absolute readouts.

Comment: Could you use a grating, and three photodiodes (one on peak, and one each just below and just above)? That way you can subtract the background. You will need to calibrate, obviously.

Comment: Can you give a little more background - are these "millions" of photons across the full spectrum? What is the source of excitation of the hydrogen? What level of precision are you looking for?

Comment: The source would be dissociated water vapor at very low percentage of total. Precision to within a percent or so.